# Does anyone know a Safari style Tab Control for Mac OS X applications?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, tabcontrol

I am looking for a tab control that is different from the default NSTabControl.  I am looking for a sample or existing control that replicates the newer style tab controls that are used within Safari, Firefox, Camino etc.

From looking into the Safari app bundle resources it seems the tabs are created from images.  I would prefer a control that already exists and has been tested rather than re-inventing the wheel though.

Thank you!

**Update:**  I found PSMTabBarControl however this doesn't work on Leopard and is very old, from 2006.  Anything that is more recent available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This publicly-available framework comes to my mind: [PSMTabBarControl](http://www.positivespinmedia.com/dev/PSMTabBarControl.html). 
It doesn't seem to be maintained recently, but might serve as a point to start from.

Comment: Thanks!  I found that just after posting the questions.  I am hoping that there is something better out there as PSMTabBarControl doesn't compile on Leopard.

Comment: Just remove the target that doesn't compile; it is an Interface Builder palette that is not compatible with current versions of Interface Builder.  The control works fine on Leopard/Snow Leopard.

Comment: Luke: Adium still uses PSMTabBarControl in current versions, and compiles and runs just fine on Snow Leopard (in fact, 1.4 will require Leopard). So, yes it does work on Leopard.